# discord.py TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Everytime i run this code i get an error message, any help would be much appreciated.**
Im using python 3.8 with visual studio code. Im new to coding so if the answer is obvious im really sorry, but thank you in advance!

Code:

```
while True:
    difficulty_setting = 2
    difficulty_progression = math.floor(score/10)
    overall_difficulty = difficulty_setting + difficulty_progression

    numbers_list = []
    for x in range(overall_difficulty):
        value = random.randint(1,9)
        numbers_list.append(value)

    answer = functools.reduce(operator.mul, numbers_list, 1)
    await ctx.send('Multiply these numbers', numbers_list)

    guess = int(input())

    if guess == answer:
        score = score + (1 * overall_difficulty)
        continue

    else:
        await ctx.send('Game over! The answer was', answer)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        await ctx.send('Score:', score, 'Time', elapsed_time)
        break
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RESUTHER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\RESUTHER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RESUTHER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `send` like `print`. `print` lets you chain together things to print out in sequence with a comma, but send requires a single string.

Eg `await ctx.send('Game over! The answer was', answer)`

Should be:

`await ctx.send(f'Game over! The answer was {answer}')`

Same with your other send calls.